# When deserializing JSON I'm getting `System.InvalidCastException`

Tags: c#, json, winforms

So, basically, I have this simple JSON serializer/deserializer application in C# where I save StringCollections into `.txt` files that have JSON inside them. So, basically, I can successfully save my JSON to a raw text file like this:

```
String path = Properties.Settings.Default.database + "//data.txt";
StringCollection data = Properties.Settings.Default.data;

File.WriteAllText(path, JsonSerializer.Serialize(data));
```

But when desirializing the file to get the object using this code:

```
string rawJson = File.ReadAllText(path);
StringCollection data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StringCollection>(rawJson);
```

It gives me this exception:

> **System.InvalidCastException**: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' to type 'System.String'.'

I searched for this one StackOverflow and found a couple of posts about it, but they really didn't solve my problem. What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** I'm using `System.Text.Json` and not `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: how you have the same variable name data as string and StringCollection .. kindly include the real code snippet so as we can support

Comment: @HanyHabib I'll change the variable names to remove confusion. These code snippets are on different functions.

Comment: Can you show sample of serialized JSON file? It is also possible that `System.Text.Json` does not support `StringCollection` deserialization.

Comment: @Nenad Sorry, the JSON file is classified, but I got my answer from Hany. Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per Microsoft documentation the below is the supported types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to :

```
.NET primitives that map to JavaScript primitives, such as numeric types, strings, and Boolean.
User-defined Plain Old CLR Objects (POCOs).
One-dimensional and jagged arrays (ArrayName[][]).
Dictionary<string,TValue> where TValue is object, JsonElement, or a POCO.
Collections from the following namespaces.
System.Collections
System.Collections.Generic
System.Collections.Immutable
```

So `StringCollection` is in `System.Collections.Specialized` namespace. So its not supported, you have 2 choices

1. Implement Custom Converter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to
2. Change Your return type to for ex: `List<string>`

Comment: Oh right! I didn't know that, because I had been using the Newtonsoft.Json library. Thanks!